Python script executable single file selecting from INFORMIX database Unspecified System Error SQLCODE=-23101
If I run IsOverUzivNoODBC.exe compiled from Python script runs fail with message

IfxPyDbi::Error: Exception('[OneDB][OneDB ODBC Driver][OneDB]Unspecified System Error =  -23101. SQLCODE=-23101')

Informix Dlls included via onedb-odbc-driver, make .exe prompt is
C:\work\python> pyinstaller IsOverUzivNoODBC.py --onefile --add-binary "C:\work\IfxPy\IfxPy\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\onedb-odbc-driver\bin;."
Due to like obtain one file executable anywhere didn't use pyodbc, which need Informix ODBC install. Am I wrong with it?
I want to generate a single executable file from my Python script. Script function is simple select from Informix database. Difficulty is in connection to Informix. Found way to connect in Python, script run fine. If got compilated .exe that included dlls, runs fail with message

IfxPyDbi::Error: Exception('[OneDB][OneDB ODBC Driver][OneDB]Unspecified System Error =  -23101. SQLCODE=-23101')

Can you help me please?
SQLCODE=-23101 is Unable to load locale categories, some issues solved here https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/issues/36 and https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/issues/24 but don't know how it can help me
Due to like obtain one file executable anywhere didn't use pyodbc, which need Informix ODBC install.
I thing problem is somewhere with including external Dll in exe or some whare with Dlls
Connecting other db like FireBird or MSSQL working like charm in Python and in .exe too, due to simple install fdb or pymssql with pip install fdb resp. pip install pymssql
I spend (lot of) time with

pip install ifxpy. Not able from py > 3.6 . Compile own IfxPy-3.0.5-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl, https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/blob/master/LocalBuildWindows.md?plain=1
indlude Dlls os.add_dll_directory('C:\work\IfxPy\IfxPy\\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\onedb-odbc-driver\\bin') ImportError: DLL load failed while importing IfxPy on Windows with Python3.8
run ifxpy resp. IfxPyDbi in Python, connetion to Informix working well.
How do I include .dll file in executable using pyinstaller?
run IsOverUzivNoODBC.exe compiled from Python -> fail

my script block with connection to Informix working in Python not in .exe
import IfxPyDbi as dbapi2

HOST = '172.16.10.40'
SERVER='server' 
PORT='123'
DATABASE = 'database'
UID = 'user'
PWD = 'paswd'
LOCALE = 'cs_cz.8859-2@sis'  #cs_CZ.912@sis #cs_cz.8859-2@sis
CLI_LOCALE = 'cs_cz.8859-2@sis' 

ConStr = "SERVER="+SERVER+";DATABASE="+DATABASE+";HOST="+HOST+";SERVICE="+PORT+";PROTOCOL=olsoctcp;DB_LOCALE="+LOCALE+";CLIENT_LOCALE="+CLI_LOCALE

cnxn = dbapi2.connect( ConStr, UID, PWD)

some attachement IsOverUzivNoODBC.spec, warn-IsOverUzivNoODBC.txt, xref-IsOverUzivNoODBC-anonym.html until 1.12.2024
https://ftncz-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/ladislav_schnaiberg_ftn_cz/EuFB4g26-ItEhl2uPUV75GkB9CqM74TTDLUtkG0Kq_LLkg?e=TrCOnY
